# How to remove empty strings from c# array?

Tags: c#

I am removing values with less than 8 characters from an array, but empty strings still remain. How to get rid of them?

```
for (int i = 0; i < reportbOR.Length; i++)
{
    border = "border:" +reportbOR[i].colorborder;
    string[] text_arr = border.Split('\n');

    foreach (var item in text_arr)
    {
        if (item.Length < 8)
            border = border.Replace(item, "");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is easier to do in a List.  If performance is not an issue, convert it to a list, remove the items you want from the list, and put the result back into an array.  Or, just use a List from the start.

Comment: Otherwise, you'll wind up copying out everything you want to keep into a new array anyway.

Comment: You can also remove empty records immediately from the `Split` function: `border.Split('\n', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: What will you do with this array after the loop? Right now, `text_arr` goes out of scope after the outer `for` loop, and this won't accomplish anything. Looking at this, I can probably get it down to a single line of code, iff I know more about how this data will be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the overload of `string.Split` which accepts a `StringSplitOptions` `enum`:

```
string[] text_arr = border.Split(new string[] { "\n" },
  StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Since it's unclear as to when you are having issues removing the empty entries, and you are also replacing strings with 8 or less characters with empty strings, you can use `Linq`:

```
text_arr = text_arr.Where(a => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(a)).ToArray();
```

You can read about the overload here: [stringsplitoptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.stringsplitoptions?view=net-6.0)

And here: [string.split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=net-6.0#system-string-split(system-string-system-stringsplitoptions))

**EDIT** Here it is in one line:

```
string[] text_arr = border.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, 
                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    .Where(a => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace(a) && a.Length >= 8)
                    .ToArray();
```

Comment: I tried your suggestions but, alas, empty lines still remain

Comment: @JOHNSMITH Then you'll need to add some example data to your post. This should work.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter out null, white space, and character length with a couple of different approaches.  We will start similar to your above code.

```
var border = new List<string>();
for(var index = 0; index < reportbOR.Length; index++)
      if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(reportbOR[index].colorBorder) && reportbOR[index].colorBorder.Length < 8)
           border.Add($"border: {reportbOR[index].colorBorder}");
```

I won't mention the `StringSplitOptions` because of @NSevens response, the documentation is pretty self explanatory but could be applicable.

One thing to denote, if you use LINQ on a `String` it will parse into a character array. But if you use your root object you could leverage LINQ.

```
var borders = reportbOR
      .Where(property => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(property.colorBorder) && property.colorBorder < 8))
      .Select(property => new $"border: {property}");
```

Also, it would be important to know that if you only care about null or empty, then use `IsNullOrEmpty`. If you want to sanitize for white-space and white-space characters then use `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
list = list.Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < reportbOR.Length; i++)
{
    var strings = $"border:{reportbOR[i].colorborder}"
        .Split(Environment.NewLine)
        .Where(str => str.Length > 8);

    border = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, strings);
}
```